# jQuery post response not set until second use

Tags: jquery

I'm super new to jQuery and would love some help with an issue I'm having. It should be pretty simple. Basically, the first alert is empty, but when I call the variable the second time it gives the expected results.

```
$.post("showcolor.php", { color: "orange"},
  function(data) {
  colorInfo = data;
});
alert(colorInfo); //empty
alert(colorInfo); //expected results
```

Can someone explain this phenomena to me?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is asynchronous. That means that the request runs in the background, while your code runs on.

The `success` callback (the `function(data)`) will run when the request is finished. In your test, that happened to be the case during the alert in line 5 was shown, before line 6 is executed.

On a slower connection, it would take even longer and line 6 would also show up empty. When the request is finished is completely random.

Bottom line: Put any code that needs to know the request results into the `success` callback.

Comment: Note: jQuery's post() function does only have one callback, so I think that "success callback" could be a bit confusing if you're super new to jQuery. It would be more obvious if the function in this case was ajax().

Answer (score 0):

An AJAX request is asynchronous meaning that the assignment of the `colorInfo = data` might be executed much later than your alerts.

Here's how it goes:

1. $.post starts an asynchronous AJAX request and immediately moves long to the next line which is the alert.
2. The alert executes and prints null because the server didn't respond yet.
3. The server responds and the callback function is invoked and the value of the colorInfo is assigned to the results of the AJAX call
4. The next alert is called and the correct value is printed.

Of course all this is pretty random. If the server is pretty fast to respond you might get even the first alert show the proper value and on the other side if the server is slow the two alerts might show the wrong value.

So the correct way is to put the alerts inside the success callback as it is only inside this anonymous function that you are guaranteed to have the data assigned:

```
$.post("showcolor.php", { color: "orange" }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Ajax request will be done about the same time as your first alert; the data haven't been returned yet.

Put the alert inside the function instead, which will be executed when the Ajax request is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with [mozilla firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/) to debug it and recognize how its work .